# Access Azure APIM only via Trusted Android, iOS & Web Apps

Tags: android, ios, azure, authentication, azure-api-management

We have Android, iOS and Azure Web app for our system which will be calling Azure APIM which is created for Azure API APP.

**Problem statement is :** 
APIM should only be accessible via Android, iOS and Azure Web app, for other clients like postman or any different mobile app or web app, APIM should give `access denied` error. 
We need a solution where header should not be passed from any of our trusted clients as this can be exploited and APIs can be called via third party clients like postman etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is not much you can do from web and end user devices. In web apps you can't safely authenticate client app, since traffic and all secrets you may want to use are visible to a user. It's a bit more safe in Android and iOS, but event there phone may be rooted or jailbroken.

So I'd advise against relying on app secret, rather think about authentication user itself. Much like any other web app works where user obtains a token and uses that token to access API. Since it's a user level token it's safe to expose it to a user. Look into OAuth. If you want to use JWT tokens APIM has validate-jwt policy to check them.

Comment: Hi Vitaliy, Thanks for your response. 
We have decided to go through the below approach : 
1. Register Android application at AAD with package name & SHA1 key
2.Generate token from android application from AAD. Note : All the inputs like ClientSecret & Id etc. will be sent to mobile application from firebase remote config 
3. Android application will send the Bearer Token in each API call of APIM proxies
4. APIM will validate the Token by checking aud claim in JWT Token Header.
5. If condition is true, then 200 response else 401
Please let us know if you have any additional inputs here

Comment: Any inputs from your end?

Comment: That may be ok, but how would you secure initial call from the app to get secrets to generate token? Keep in mind, that one can easily add a self signed certificate to a phone, have a proxy between phone and your services, and see all traffic in clear text. No root or jailbreak needed for that.

Comment: My recommendation would be to treat all mobile apps as web apps and apply same restrictions as in web. If that is a deal breaker for your scenario, then see what mobile platform offers you in terms of storing secrets in a way inaccessible to end user. That will at least secure you from non rooted/jailbroken devices. Ideally you should still be prepared to stop service abuse.